# "Incorrect Format" reference error while building Web Deployment project in TeamCity

Tags: vb.net, deployment, msbuild, teamcity, web-deployment-project

I began setting up a TeamCity server a couple days ago for use in automated testing and CI.  We mainly do VB.net web apps and up until now, it had been checking out things and building just fine.

A problem came up when I tried to add actual deployment into the mix.  I saw this article:

http://www.diaryofaninja.com/blog/2010/05/09/automated-site-deployments-with-teamcity-deployment-projects-amp-svn

referenced all over the place as a good guide, so I followed the steps relating to setting up a Web Deployment project and rigging TeamCity to run it.  Basically, it recommends setting up a new build configuration in VS2010 called "Deployment" which builds the Web Deployment project, then creating a build configuration in TC that targets it.

The issue is that the web deployment project won't compile when run under TeamCity.  The regular build works just fine, but if I set MSBuild to use the build configuration that includes the Web Deployment project, it crashes halfway through and gives an error about attempting to load the System.Data.OracleClient assembly in an incorrect format.  I assume this means a 32-bit/64-bit error, especially since my development machine is a 32-bit box, and the build server is 64, but I don't know why this is happening, especially when the regular build works, and nothing in my project involves using an Oracle database.

I saw in the log that there's a warning about missing reference assemblies for the 4.0 framework, so I headed off to the MS website and downloaded the SDK, but that didn't change anything.  At this point, I'm stuck, and I didn't see anything already here on Stack Overflow that looked quite like this.  I'll attach the log below.  Have I missed something simple?  Anybody else run into a problem like this?

```
[10:46:05]: Project "MyTools.sln.teamcity.patch.tcprojx" (TeamCity_Generated_Build target(s)):
[10:46:05]:  [Project "MyTools.sln.teamcity.patch.tcprojx" (TeamCity_Generated_Build target(s)):] Project "MyTools.sln" (Rebuild target(s)):
[10:46:05]:   [Project "MyTools.sln" (Rebuild target(s)):] Building solution configuration "Deployment|Any CPU".
[10:46:05]:   [Project "MyTools.sln" (Rebuild target(s)):] Project "MyTools.vbproj" (Rebuild target(s)):
[10:46:05]:    [Project "MyTools.vbproj" (Rebuild target(s)):] Creating directory "obj\Deployment\".
[10:46:05]:    [Project "MyTools.vbproj" (Rebuild target(s)):] Project "MyLib.vbproj" (Clean target(s)):
[10:46:05]:     [Project "MyLib.vbproj" (Clean target(s)):] Creating directory "obj\Deployment\".
[10:46:05]:    [Project "MyTools.vbproj" (Rebuild target(s)):] Project "AutomatedFrontEndClasses.vbproj" (Clean target(s)):
[10:46:05]:     [Project "AutomatedFrontEndClasses.vbproj" (Clean target(s)):] Creating directory "obj\Deployment\".
[10:46:05]:     [Project "AutomatedFrontEndClasses.vbproj" (Clean target(s)):] Project "MyLib.vbproj" (Clean target(s)):
[10:46:05]:    [Project "MyTools.vbproj" (Rebuild target(s)):] C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(847, 9): warning MSB3644: The reference assemblies for framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.0" were not found. To resolve this, install the SDK or Targeting Pack for this framework version or retarget your application to a version of the framework for which you have the SDK or Targeting Pack installed. Note that assemblies will be resolved from the Global Assembly Cache (GAC) and will be used in place of reference assemblies. Therefore your assembly may not be correctly targeted for the framework you intend.
[10:46:05]:    [Project "MyTools.vbproj" (Rebuild target(s)):] Project "MyLib.vbproj" (default targets):
[10:46:05]:     [Project "MyLib.vbproj" (default targets):] C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(847, 9): warning MSB3644: The reference assemblies for framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.0" were not found. To resolve this, install the SDK or Targeting Pack for this framework version or retarget your application to a version of the framework for which you have the SDK or Targeting Pack installed. Note that assemblies will be resolved from the Global Assembly Cache (GAC) and will be used in place of reference assemblies. Therefore your assembly may not be correctly targeted for the framework you intend.
[10:46:05]:     [Project "MyLib.vbproj" (default targets):] Creating directory "bin\Deployment\".
[10:46:09]:     [Project "MyLib.vbproj" (default targets):] C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Vbc.exe /noconfig /imports:Microsoft.VisualBasic,System,System.Collections,System.Collections.Generic,System.Data,System.Diagnostics,System.Linq /optioncompare:Text /optionstrict+ /optioninfer- /nostdlib /rootnamespace:MyLib /sdkpath:C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319 /define:"CONFIG=\"Deployment\",_MyType=\"Windows\",PLATFORM=\"AnyCPU\"" /link:D:\TeamCityBuildAgent\work\c18407eaf8486b52\MyLib\MyLib\bin\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.dll /reference:C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo\10.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91\Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo.dll,C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc\10.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91\Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc.dll,C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo\10.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91\Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo.dll,C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlEnum\10.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91\Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlEnum.dll,D:\TeamCityBuildAgent\work\c18407eaf8486b52\MyLib\MyLib\bin\NVelocity.dll,C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll,C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.configuration\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.configuration.dll,C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Core\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Core.dll,C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Data.DataSetExtensions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll,C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Data\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.dll,C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Data.Linq\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.Linq.dll,C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.DirectoryServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.DirectoryServices.dll,C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll,C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Drawing\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Drawing.dll,C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime.Serialization\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Runtime.Serialization.dll,C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Security\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Security.dll,C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.ServiceModel.dll,C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel.Web\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ServiceModel.Web.dll,C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Abstractions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.Abstractions.dll,C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.ApplicationServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.ApplicationServices.dll,C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Web\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.dll,C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Extensions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.Extensions.dll,"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET MVC 2\Assemblies\System.Web.Mvc.dll",C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Services\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.Services.dll,C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Windows.Forms\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Windows.Forms.dll,C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.dll,C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml.Linq\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.Linq.dll /out:obj\Deployment\MyLib.dll /resource:obj\Deployment\MyLib.Resources.resources /resource:obj\Deployment\MyLib.Logos.resources /resource:obj\Deployment\MyLib.Scorecard.resources /resource:obj\Deployment\MyLib.keys.resources /resource:Client\RockCounty\QuarterlyPtsSummaryPdfPage1.xhtml.vm,MyLib.QuarterlyPtsSummaryPdfPage1.xhtml.vm /resource:Client\RockCounty\QuarterlyPtsSummaryPdfPage1Apology.xhtml.vm,MyLib.QuarterlyPtsSummaryPdfPage1Apology.xhtml.vm /resource:Client\Convergys\ConvergysKyrkynChecklist.xhtml.vm,MyLib.ConvergysKyrkynChecklist.xhtml.vm /resource:Client\RockCounty\QuarterlyPtsSummaryPdfPage2.xhtml.vm,MyLib.QuarterlyPtsSummaryPdfPage2.xhtml.vm /resource:Client\RockCounty\RockCountyPtsFaxPdf.xhtml.vm,MyLib.RockCountyPtsFaxPdf.xhtml.vm /resource:Resources\NVelocity\WelcomeLetterReport.vm,MyLib.WelcomeLetterReport.vm /resource:Client\ValleyView\ValleyViewChecklistPdfResources.zip,MyLib.ValleyViewChecklistPdfResources.zip /resource:Client\Sjchs\SjchsChecklistPdfResources.zip,MyLib.SjchsChecklistPdfResources.zip /resource:Providers\PcpAutoSelect\PcpAutoSelectPdfResources.zip,MyLib.PcpAutoSelectPdfResources.zip /resource:Resources\NatLimeKyrkynChecklistPdfResources.zip,MyLib.NatLimeKyrkynChecklistPdfResources.zip /resource:Resources\ConvergysKyrkynChecklistPdfResources.zip,MyLib.ConvergysKyrkynChecklistPdfResources.zip /resource:Resources\KyrkynScorecardPdfResources.zip,MyLib.KyrkynScorecardPdfResources.zip /resource:Client\Sjchs\SjchsChecklistPage1.htm,MyLib.SjchsChecklistPage1.htm /resource:Client\Sjchs\SjchsChecklistPage2.htm,MyLib.SjchsChecklistPage2.htm /resource:Providers\PcpAutoSelect\PcpAutoSelectNotificationPage1.htm,MyLib.PcpAutoSelectNotificationPage1.htm /resource:Providers\PcpAutoSelect\PcpAutoSelectNotificationPage2.htm,MyLib.PcpAutoSelectNotificationPage2.htm /resource:Client\Watco\WatcoPCPForm.pdf,MyLib.WatcoPCPForm.pdf /resource:Client\Watco\Watco-Newsletter3.pdf,MyLib.Watco-Newsletter3.pdf /resource:Client\WAICU\WAICU_Checklist_Back.pdf,MyLib.WAICU_Checklist_Back.pdf /resource:Client\WAICU\WAICU_Checklist_FrontBG.pdf,MyLib.WAICU_Checklist_FrontBG.pdf /resource:Client\WAICU\WAICU_FrontBG_ALL_YES.pdf,MyLib.WAICU_FrontBG_ALL_YES.pdf /resource:Client\WAICU\WAICU_KYRKYNCard.pdf,MyLib.WAICU_KYRKYNCard.pdf /resource:Client\RockCounty\RockCountyPtsFax.pdf,MyLib.RockCountyPtsFax.pdf /resource:Client\ValleyView\UpdValleyViewChecklistReqs.sql,MyLib.UpdValleyViewChecklistReqs.sql /resource:Client\ValleyView\SelValleyViewChecklistReqs.sql,MyLib.SelValleyViewChecklistReqs.sql /resource:Providers\PcpAutoSelect\SelPcpAutoSelectData.sql,MyLib.SelPcpAutoSelectData.sql /resource:Client\NatLime\SqlNatLimeKyrkynChecklistData.sql,MyLib.SqlNatLimeKyrkynChecklistData.sql /resource:Client\Convergys\SqlConvergysKyrkynChecklistData.sql,MyLib.SqlConvergysKyrkynChecklistData.sql /resource:Client\Sjchs\SjchsEligTrackingChecklist.xml,MyLib.SjchsEligTrackingChecklist.xml /resource:Resources\XML\SSN.xml,MyLib.SSN.xml /resource:Client\WAICU\WAICU_CheckedBoxLarge.jpg,MyLib.WAICU_CheckedBoxLarge.jpg /resource:Client\WAICU\WAICU_UncheckedBoxLarge.jpg,MyLib.WAICU_UncheckedBoxLarge.jpg /resource:Client\WAICU\WAICU_WarningBox1.png,MyLib.WAICU_WarningBox1.png /resource:Resources\XSLT\Beautify.xslt,MyLib.Beautify.xslt /resource:Resources\XSLT\CompressWhitespace.xslt,MyLib.CompressWhitespace.xslt /target:library ...giant list of source files... "D:\TeamCityBuildAgent\temp\buildTmp\.NETFramework,Version=v4.0.AssemblyAttributes.vb"
[10:46:18]:     [Project "MyLib.vbproj" (default targets):] MyLib -> D:\TeamCityBuildAgent\work\c18407eaf8486b52\MyLib\MyLib\bin\Deployment\MyLib.dll
[10:46:18]:    [Project "MyTools.vbproj" (Rebuild target(s)):] Project "AutomatedFrontEndClasses.vbproj" (default targets):
[10:46:18]:     [Project "AutomatedFrontEndClasses.vbproj" (default targets):] C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(847, 9): warning MSB3644: The reference assemblies for framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.0" were not found. To resolve this, install the SDK or Targeting Pack for this framework version or retarget your application to a version of the framework for which you have the SDK or Targeting Pack installed. Note that assemblies will be resolved from the Global Assembly Cache (GAC) and will be used in place of reference assemblies. Therefore your assembly may not be correctly targeted for the framework you intend.
[10:46:18]:     [Project "AutomatedFrontEndClasses.vbproj" (default targets):] Creating directory "bin\Deployment\".
[10:46:18]:     [Project "AutomatedFrontEndClasses.vbproj" (default targets):] Project "MyLib.vbproj" (default targets):
[10:46:18]:     [Project "AutomatedFrontEndClasses.vbproj" (default targets):] Project "MyLib.vbproj" (GetNativeManifest target(s)):
[10:46:18]:     [Project "AutomatedFrontEndClasses.vbproj" (default targets):] Processing resource file "My Project\Resources.resx" into "obj\Deployment\AutomatedFrontEndClasses.Resources.resources".
[10:46:18]:     [Project "AutomatedFrontEndClasses.vbproj" (default targets):] Skipping target "GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
[10:46:18]:     [Project "AutomatedFrontEndClasses.vbproj" (default targets):] C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Vbc.exe /noconfig /imports:Microsoft.VisualBasic,System,System.Collections,System.Collections.Generic,System.Data,System.Diagnostics,System.Linq,System.Xml.Linq /optioncompare:Binary /optionexplicit+ /optionstrict:custom /optioninfer+ /nostdlib /rootnamespace:AutomatedFrontEndClasses /sdkpath:C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319 /define:"CONFIG=\"Deployment\",_MyType=\"Windows\",PLATFORM=\"AnyCPU\"" /reference:D:\TeamCityBuildAgent\work\c18407eaf8486b52\MyTools\AutomatedFrontEndClasses\bin\ceTe.DynamicPDF.20.dll,D:\TeamCityBuildAgent\work\c18407eaf8486b52\MyLib\MyLib\bin\Deployment\MyLib.dll,C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Configuration\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Configuration.dll,C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Core\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Core.dll,C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Data.DataSetExtensions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll,C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Data\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.dll,C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Data.Linq\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.Linq.dll,C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll,C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime.Serialization\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Runtime.Serialization.dll,C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.dll,C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml.Linq\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.Linq.dll /filealign:512 /out:obj\Deployment\AutomatedFrontEndClasses.dll /resource:obj\Deployment\AutomatedFrontEndClasses.Resources.resources /target:library Checklist\SJCHSChecklistGen.vb Checklist\ValleyViewChecklistGen.vb Config.vb ExportedClassAttribute.vb ExportedMethodAttribute.vb ExportedParameterAttribute.vb Misc\PcpAutoSelectLetterGen.vb "My Project\AssemblyInfo.vb" "My Project\Application.Designer.vb" "My Project\Resources.Designer.vb" "My Project\Settings.Designer.vb" PluginBaseClass.vb Scorecard\ScorecardGen.vb Test\TestChecklistGen.vb "D:\TeamCityBuildAgent\temp\buildTmp\.NETFramework,Version=v4.0.AssemblyAttributes.vb"
[10:46:19]:     [Project "AutomatedFrontEndClasses.vbproj" (default targets):] Project "MyLib.vbproj" (GetCopyToOutputDirectoryItems target(s)):
[10:46:19]:     [Project "AutomatedFrontEndClasses.vbproj" (default targets):] Copying file from "obj\Deployment\AutomatedFrontEndClasses.dll" to "bin\Deployment\AutomatedFrontEndClasses.dll".
[10:46:19]:     [Project "AutomatedFrontEndClasses.vbproj" (default targets):] AutomatedFrontEndClasses -> D:\TeamCityBuildAgent\work\c18407eaf8486b52\MyTools\AutomatedFrontEndClasses\bin\Deployment\AutomatedFrontEndClasses.dll
[10:46:19]:    [Project "MyTools.vbproj" (Rebuild target(s)):] Project "MyLib.vbproj" (GetNativeManifest target(s)):
[10:46:19]:    [Project "MyTools.vbproj" (Rebuild target(s)):] Project "AutomatedFrontEndClasses.vbproj" (GetNativeManifest target(s)):
[10:46:19]:    [Project "MyTools.vbproj" (Rebuild target(s)):] Processing resource file "My Project\Resources.resx" into "obj\Deployment\MyTools.Resources.resources".
[10:46:19]:    [Project "MyTools.vbproj" (Rebuild target(s)):] Skipping target "GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
[10:46:19]:    [Project "MyTools.vbproj" (Rebuild target(s)):] C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Vbc.exe /noconfig /imports:Microsoft.VisualBasic,System,System.Collections,System.Collections.Generic,System.Data,System.Linq,System.Xml.Linq,System.Diagnostics,System.Collections.Specialized,System.Configuration,System.Text,System.Text.RegularExpressions,System.Web,System.Web.Caching,System.Web.SessionState,System.Web.Security,System.Web.Profile,System.Web.UI,System.Web.UI.WebControls,System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts,System.Web.UI.HtmlControls /optioncompare:Binary /optionexplicit+ /optionstrict:custom /optioninfer+ /nostdlib /rootnamespace:MyTools /sdkpath:C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319 /define:"CONFIG=\"Deployment\",_MyType=\"Custom\",PLATFORM=\"AnyCPU\"" /reference:D:\TeamCityBuildAgent\work\c18407eaf8486b52\MyTools\AutomatedFrontEndClasses\bin\Deployment\AutomatedFrontEndClasses.dll,D:\TeamCityBuildAgent\work\c18407eaf8486b52\MyLib\MyLib\bin\Deployment\MyLib.dll,C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Configuration\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Configuration.dll,C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Core\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Core.dll,C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Data.DataSetExtensions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll,C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Data\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.dll,C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Data.Linq\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.Linq.dll,C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll,C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Drawing\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Drawing.dll,C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.EnterpriseServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.EnterpriseServices.dll,C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime.Serialization\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Runtime.Serialization.dll,C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.ServiceModel.dll,C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.ApplicationServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.ApplicationServices.dll,C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Web\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.dll,C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.DynamicData\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.DynamicData.dll,C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Entity\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Web.Entity.dll,C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Extensions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.Extensions.dll,C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Services\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.Services.dll,C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.dll,C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml.Linq\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.Linq.dll /out:obj\Deployment\MyTools.dll /resource:obj\Deployment\MyTools.Resources.resources /target:library ...(list o' source files)... "D:\TeamCityBuildAgent\temp\buildTmp\.NETFramework,Version=v4.0.AssemblyAttributes.vb"
[10:46:20]:    [Project "MyTools.vbproj" (Rebuild target(s)):] Copying file from "D:\TeamCityBuildAgent\work\c18407eaf8486b52\MyTools\AutomatedFrontEndClasses\bin\Deployment\AutomatedFrontEndClasses.dll" to "bin\AutomatedFrontEndClasses.dll".
[10:46:20]:    [Project "MyTools.vbproj" (Rebuild target(s)):] Copying file from "D:\TeamCityBuildAgent\work\c18407eaf8486b52\MyLib\MyLib\bin\Deployment\MyLib.dll" to "bin\MyLib.dll".
[10:46:20]:    [Project "MyTools.vbproj" (Rebuild target(s)):] Project "MyLib.vbproj" (GetCopyToOutputDirectoryItems target(s)):
[10:46:20]:    [Project "MyTools.vbproj" (Rebuild target(s)):] Project "AutomatedFrontEndClasses.vbproj" (GetCopyToOutputDirectoryItems target(s)):
[10:46:20]:    [Project "MyTools.vbproj" (Rebuild target(s)):] Copying file from "obj\Deployment\MyTools.dll" to "bin\MyTools.dll".
[10:46:20]:    [Project "MyTools.vbproj" (Rebuild target(s)):] MyTools -> D:\TeamCityBuildAgent\work\c18407eaf8486b52\MyTools\MyTools\bin\MyTools.dll
[10:46:20]:   [Project "MyTools.sln" (Rebuild target(s)):] Project "AutomatedFrontEndClasses.vbproj" (Rebuild target(s)):
[10:46:20]:   [Project "MyTools.sln" (Rebuild target(s)):] Project "MyLib.vbproj" (Rebuild target(s)):
[10:46:20]:   [Project "MyTools.sln" (Rebuild target(s)):] Project "MyTools.vbproj_deploy.wdproj.metaproj" (Rebuild target(s)):
[10:46:20]:    [Project "MyTools.vbproj_deploy.wdproj.metaproj" (Rebuild target(s)):] Project "MyTools.vbproj" (Rebuild target(s)):
[10:46:20]:    [Project "MyTools.vbproj_deploy.wdproj.metaproj" (Rebuild target(s)):] Project "MyTools.vbproj_deploy.wdproj" (Rebuild target(s)):
[10:46:20]:     [Project "MyTools.vbproj_deploy.wdproj" (Rebuild target(s)):] Creating directory "obj\Deployment\".
[10:46:20]:     [Project "MyTools.vbproj_deploy.wdproj" (Rebuild target(s)):] Project "MyTools.vbproj" (GetTargetPath target(s)):
[10:46:20]:     [Project "MyTools.vbproj_deploy.wdproj" (Rebuild target(s)):] Project "MyTools.vbproj" (GetNativeManifest target(s)):
[10:46:20]:     [Project "MyTools.vbproj_deploy.wdproj" (Rebuild target(s)):] C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\WebDeployment\v10.0\Microsoft.WebDeployment.targets(1129, 5): warning MSB3644: The reference assemblies for framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.0" were not found. To resolve this, install the SDK or Targeting Pack for this framework version or retarget your application to a version of the framework for which you have the SDK or Targeting Pack installed. Note that assemblies will be resolved from the Global Assembly Cache (GAC) and will be used in place of reference assemblies. Therefore your assembly may not be correctly targeted for the framework you intend.
[10:46:22]:     [Project "MyTools.vbproj_deploy.wdproj" (Rebuild target(s)):] Copying file from "C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_64\System.Data.OracleClient\2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.OracleClient.dll" to "D:\TeamCityBuildAgent\work\c18407eaf8486b52\MyTools\MyTools\bin\System.Data.OracleClient.dll".
[10:46:22]:     [Project "MyTools.vbproj_deploy.wdproj" (Rebuild target(s)):] Copying file from "C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_64\System.Transactions\2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Transactions.dll" to "D:\TeamCityBuildAgent\work\c18407eaf8486b52\MyTools\MyTools\bin\System.Transactions.dll".
[10:46:22]:     [Project "MyTools.vbproj_deploy.wdproj" (Rebuild target(s)):] Copying file from "C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_64\System.EnterpriseServices\2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.EnterpriseServices.dll" to "D:\TeamCityBuildAgent\work\c18407eaf8486b52\MyTools\MyTools\bin\System.EnterpriseServices.dll".
[10:46:22]:     [Project "MyTools.vbproj_deploy.wdproj" (Rebuild target(s)):] Copying file from "C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_64\System.EnterpriseServices\2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.EnterpriseServices.Wrapper.dll" to "D:\TeamCityBuildAgent\work\c18407eaf8486b52\MyTools\MyTools\bin\System.EnterpriseServices.Wrapper.dll".
[10:46:22]:     [Project "MyTools.vbproj_deploy.wdproj" (Rebuild target(s)):] C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_compiler.exe -v /MyTools.vbproj -p D:\TeamCityBuildAgent\work\c18407eaf8486b52\MyTools\MyTools -u -f -c obj\Deployment\TempBuildDir 
[10:46:26]:     [Project "MyTools.vbproj_deploy.wdproj" (Rebuild target(s)):] ASPNETCOMPILER error ASPCONFIG: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.OracleClient' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.
[10:46:27]: MSBuild output:

[10:46:27]: "D:\TeamCityBuildAgent\work\c18407eaf8486b52\MyTools\MyTools.sln.teamcity.patch.tcprojx" (TeamCity_Generated_Build target) (1) ->
[10:46:27]: "D:\TeamCityBuildAgent\work\c18407eaf8486b52\MyTools\MyTools.sln" (Rebuild target) (2) ->
[10:46:27]: "D:\TeamCityBuildAgent\work\c18407eaf8486b52\MyTools\MyTools\MyTools.vbproj" (Rebuild target) (3) ->
[10:46:27]: "D:\TeamCityBuildAgent\work\c18407eaf8486b52\MyTools\AutomatedFrontEndClasses\AutomatedFrontEndClasses.vbproj" (default target) (5:2) ->
[10:46:27]: (GetReferenceAssemblyPaths target) -> 
[10:46:27]:   C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(847,9): warning MSB3644: The reference assemblies for framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.0" were not found. To resolve this, install the SDK or Targeting Pack for this framework version or retarget your application to a version of the framework for which you have the SDK or Targeting Pack installed. Note that assemblies will be resolved from the Global Assembly Cache (GAC) and will be used in place of reference assemblies. Therefore your assembly may not be correctly targeted for the framework you intend. [D:\TeamCityBuildAgent\work\c18407eaf8486b52\MyTools\AutomatedFrontEndClasses\AutomatedFrontEndClasses.vbproj]
[10:46:27]: "D:\TeamCityBuildAgent\work\c18407eaf8486b52\MyTools\MyTools.sln.teamcity.patch.tcprojx" (TeamCity_Generated_Build target) (1) ->
[10:46:27]: "D:\TeamCityBuildAgent\work\c18407eaf8486b52\MyTools\MyTools.sln" (Rebuild target) (2) ->
[10:46:27]: "D:\TeamCityBuildAgent\work\c18407eaf8486b52\MyTools\MyTools.vbproj_deploy\MyTools.vbproj_deploy.wdproj.metaproj" (Rebuild target) (6) ->
[10:46:27]: "D:\TeamCityBuildAgent\work\c18407eaf8486b52\MyTools\MyTools.vbproj_deploy\MyTools.vbproj_deploy.wdproj" (Rebuild target) (7) ->
[10:46:27]:   C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\WebDeployment\v10.0\Microsoft.WebDeployment.targets(1129,5): warning MSB3644: The reference assemblies for framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.0" were not found. To resolve this, install the SDK or Targeting Pack for this framework version or retarget your application to a version of the framework for which you have the SDK or Targeting Pack installed. Note that assemblies will be resolved from the Global Assembly Cache (GAC) and will be used in place of reference assemblies. Therefore your assembly may not be correctly targeted for the framework you intend. [D:\TeamCityBuildAgent\work\c18407eaf8486b52\MyTools\MyTools.vbproj_deploy\MyTools.vbproj_deploy.wdproj]
[10:46:27]: "D:\TeamCityBuildAgent\work\c18407eaf8486b52\MyTools\MyTools.sln.teamcity.patch.tcprojx" (TeamCity_Generated_Build target) (1) ->
[10:46:27]: "D:\TeamCityBuildAgent\work\c18407eaf8486b52\MyTools\MyTools.sln" (Rebuild target) (2) ->
[10:46:27]: "D:\TeamCityBuildAgent\work\c18407eaf8486b52\MyTools\MyTools.vbproj_deploy\MyTools.vbproj_deploy.wdproj.metaproj" (Rebuild target) (6) ->
[10:46:27]: "D:\TeamCityBuildAgent\work\c18407eaf8486b52\MyTools\MyTools.vbproj_deploy\MyTools.vbproj_deploy.wdproj" (Rebuild target) (7) ->
[10:46:27]: (AspNetCompiler target) -> 
[10:46:27]:   ASPNETCOMPILER : error ASPCONFIG: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.OracleClient' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. [D:\TeamCityBuildAgent\work\c18407eaf8486b52\MyTools\MyTools.vbproj_deploy\MyTools.vbproj_deploy.wdproj]
[10:46:27]:     33 Warning(s)
[10:46:27]:     1 Error(s)
[10:46:27]: Time Elapsed 00:00:21.56
[10:46:27]: Publishing artifacts
[10:46:27]:  [Publishing artifacts] Paths to publish: [teamcity-info.xml]
[10:46:27]:  [Publishing artifacts] Publishing files
[10:46:27]: Build finished
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out that I had multiple problems with the set up, but I think I've gotten through them.  All were, as far as I could tell, a result of not having a full installation of visual studio on the build server.

Basically I was missing reference assemblies for the 4.0 framework, which caused MSBuild to copy in some assemblies from the GAC so it could use them instead.  My project is 32-bit, but the machine is 64-bit, so when it went to get assemblies, it grabbed 64-bit ones, which caused the "incorrect format" error.

After fixing this by installing the full 4.0 SDK, I found that the build still wouldn't work because several files that the Web Deployment targets were expecting to be in place (because they come with Visual Studio) weren't actually there.  I followed the advice I found in the third comment here:

[http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdevtools/archive/2010/05/26/visual-studio-2010-web-deployment-projects-rtw-available-now.aspx](https://web.archive.org/web/20120702130644/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/webdevtools/archive/2010/05/26/visual-studio-2010-web-deployment-projects-rtw-available-now.aspx)

and copied them over from my development machine.  The web deployment project now builds just fine.

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar error after I switched my project from .Net4.0 to .Net4.5. 
The TeamCity compilation started to fail and gave the following error:

`SGEN An attempt was made to load an assembly with an incorrect format: C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_64\System.Data\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.dll`

In the end I solved it by manually creating the following folder and copying the missing dlls in it: 
    'c:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\'

Comment: corrected path c:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\

Comment: Worked for me. 1+ for this.

Comment: I was unable to install v4.5 on Windows 8.1 as it said it was already included so I ended up copying the directory from my PC and onto the server and it finally resolved this for me. Thanks for finally helping me get the bottom of it!

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to make sure you have have the .NET Frameworks SDK (aka Targeting Pack, aks Developer Pack) for the versions you may want to target. They can be found and are enumerated nicely at [.NET SDKs and Downloads](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/p/dotnet_sdks.aspx)